# jQuery (or Javascript) Way to Format a Number Based on a Given C#/VBA/Java Format String

Tags: javascript, jquery, formatting, string-formatting

I have a number being returned from a database with an associated format string. For the purposes of this example think 2 columns.

```
Value      FormatString  ---->  DESIRED OUTPUT FROM JAVASCRIPT/JQUERY
-----      ------------         -------------------------------------
100        #0.00                100.00    
100000     #0,.0K               100.0K
.193       #0.0%                19.3%
```

Formatting options include # of decimal points, thousands separator or not, magnitude (K,M,B), percent, currency, etc. The format strings work just fine in C# and VBA (and I believe Java uses the same format strings).

I am looking for a javascript way (using whatever library is applicable, jQuery preferred) to provide the raw value and the format string and have it return a formatted number.

We are trying to re-write an app and this is what the database is giving us...can't change the database (and not sure I would want to either as the database shouldn't care about formatting the numbers for display).

Worst case: we have to change all the format strings to something javascript likes...but even then I have yet to find a usable solution that accepts a format string.

EDIT

I have looked into the following libraries/plugins/tools.

1. [Numeral.js](http://numeraljs.com/)
2. [DecimalFormat.js](https://gist.github.com/oskansavli/822382)
3. [jquery-numberformatter](http://code.google.com/p/jquery-numberformatter/)

All have varying levels of "correctness" (as it applies to the C#/VBA format strings). I could probably hack something together using 1 of the above as a starting point but want to see if there is something already out there.

Numeral.js feels like the most promising but it doesn't handle magnitude the way I need (it wants to auto determine the magnitude for you based on the value passed in). This feels like the "easiest" one to alter if that is the ultimate solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

And after sleeping on it and trying to google again the morning I believe I have found what I need.

[flexible-js](https://code.google.com/p/flexible-js-formatting/)

This appears to be working as I would expect. Don't know if it handles every use case perfectly but based on initial testing it looks to be working as I need.